# UIPATH - Concatenate two excel cells in an array

Tags: arrays, uipath

What's the best way to concatenate two cells from the same Excel file in an Array using only UIPATH.

I currently have a first array filled with cities names and a second one filled with postalCode. Both come from the same Excel table with 2 column [city] and [PostalCode].
Now I'm looking for made a third array with (postal code + " - " + city) using only UIPATH

May I have some help ?

Comment: Just use a simple For Each loop on that DataTable. You should go for the UiPath Academy. Did you already?

Comment: I'm currently on it yes, I tried to make personal project next to it to improve myself faster. I can't use For each loop because I have 2 different array, this is not a datatable

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't understand well why you couldn't read the cells as a data table and filter the table.

But I assumed that the arrays have the same length, simply, you could create the third array empty with the same length as the others. Then into a for each loop assign the value of the first and second array to the third.

Something like that (index is the "Index" propriety of the "For each" activity):
[image]
[image]

Regards, Gio